# Cannot identify image file '/tmp/image.png'

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, object-detection

I am working on training an object detection model on Google Colab based on [1](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_object_detection). After training the model, I want to test the model on new image as in this [Test the TFLite model on your image](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_object_detection#optional_test_the_tflite_model_on_your_image). I am obtaining an error when running the code in [Run object detection and show the detection results](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_object_detection#run_object_detection_and_show_the_detection_results):

```
INPUT_IMAGE_URL = "https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-ml-data/img/openimage/3/2520/3916261642_0a504acd60_o.jpg"
DETECTION_THRESHOLD = 0.3

TEMP_FILE = '/tmp/image.png'
!wget -q -O $TEMP_FILE $INPUT_IMAGE_URL
im = Image.open(TEMP_FILE)
im.thumbnail((512, 512), Image.ANTIALIAS)
im.save(TEMP_FILE, 'PNG')

# Load the TFLite model
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=model_path)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Run inference and draw detection result on the local copy of the original file
detection_result_image = run_odt_and_draw_results(
    TEMP_FILE,
    interpreter,
    threshold=DETECTION_THRESHOLD
)

# Show the detection result
Image.fromarray(detection_result_image)
```

Can someone please explain to me what is the following code part used for :

```
TEMP_FILE = '/tmp/image.png'

!wget -q -O $TEMP_FILE $INPUT_IMAGE_URL
im = Image.open(TEMP_FILE)
im.thumbnail((512, 512), Image.ANTIALIAS)
im.save(TEMP_FILE, 'PNG')
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You say you're getting an error: what is the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
# define local path to save image
TEMP_FILE = '/tmp/image.png'

# In a notebook, run bash command to download image locally from URL
!wget -q -O $TEMP_FILE $INPUT_IMAGE_URL

# Open the image (with Pillow library most likely)
im = Image.open(TEMP_FILE)

# Resize it to 512*512 pixels with the antialiasing resampling algorithm 
im.thumbnail((512, 512), Image.ANTIALIAS)

# Save output image to local file
im.save(TEMP_FILE, 'PNG')
```

Comment: Is this exclamation point before `wget` a specific notebook syntax for running cli commands?

Comment: @Jasper In Jupyter notebooks, the exclamation mark `!` executes commands from the underlying operating system. For example, to run the list directory command `ls` (in a Unixlike OS) within your Jupyter notebook, call `!ls` in any cell.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation !! Appreciate your help